# Laravel - getting ID from a URL and parsing URL having dash (-) into it

Tags: laravel

i have an ID in a url. its like this

```
http://mysite.test/category/subcategory/title-13
```

now in Laravel.

i want to parse this part of URL in my web.php route file so that i can detect and pass them in a function.

```
category/subcategory/title-13
```

and route must be like this.

```
Route::get('{category}/{subcategory_slug}/{slug}-{id}/', 'ItemsController@item')
```

i tried this but its not working. because of "-"

and here title has dashes (-) into it as well. like

```
http://mysite.test//jobs/articles/get-your-dream-job-16
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `slug` placeholder consumes everything up to the next slash, including the `-`, so the rest never matches.

---

Laravel lets you add your own pattern against which to match a placeholder, [using the `where` method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-parameters).

If you set your `slug`'s pattern to exclude the `-` character, it should work as you expect.

```php
Route::get('{category}/{subcategory_slug}/{slug}-{id}/', 'ItemsController@item')
     ->where('slug', '[^-]+');
```

---

If your `slug` itself contains dashes, then you can use a lookahead to make sure there's always at least one dash left:

```php
Route::get('{category}/{subcategory_slug}/{slug}-{id}/', 'ItemsController@item')
     ->where('slug', '.+(?=-)');
```

Comment: you are successfully able to detect dash (-) and parse it but my title itself has slashes. "/jobs/articles/get-your-dream-job-16". let me edit the original post too.

Comment: @AhmedAboud - that's taking about the parameter's name. So `subcategory_slug`, not `subcategory-slug`.

Comment: @JosephSilber oh i just noticed that slug and id are separate parameters , thanks for the note